# Implementing the intelligent recursive algorithm in matlab

Tags: algorithm, image, matlab, image-processing

Well am referring the following [paper](http://www.iaeng.org/publication/WCECS2011/WCECS2011_pp67-71.pdf) and trying to implement the algorithm as given in matlab

The only problem is how do i find a noisy pixel i.e **Pixel with impulse noise**?

X seems to be the impulse pixel in an image which i have to calculate

_

```
____________________________________________ 
Input – Noisy Image h 
_______________________________________________ 
Step 1: Compute X 
             for every pixel repeat steps from 2 to 7 
Step 2: Initialize w = 3 
Step 3: If X(i,j) ≠ Impulse pixel 
                 goto step 7  
Step 4: ∆i,j = { h(i1,j1) | i-(w-1)/2 ≤ i1 ≤ i+(w-1)/2,  
                                                j-(w-1)/2 ≤ j1 ≤ j+(w-1)/2} 
             b=no. of  black pixels in the window 
             w=no. of white pixels in the window 
Step 5: If ∆i,j ≠ NULL 
                    p(i,j) = mean(∆i,j
) 
                    d(i,j) = | h(i,j) – p(i,j) | 
            else   if (w < wmax) 
                           w=w+2 
                           goto step 4 
           else   
                     if (b>w) 
                           h(i,j)=0 
                    else 
                           h(i,j)=255 
Step 7: Goto next pixel 
Step 8: Calculate threshold t, from detailed coefficient  
                  matrix d 
            for every pixel 
Step 9: If (d(i,j)>t) 
                    h(i,j)=p(i,j) 
____________________________
```

**Edit:** To implement the PSM or the median filter method we 
need to set some parameters and a threshold value. This 
threshold value is dependent on the image and the noise 
density. So, to restore different images we need to check for 
a range of threshold values and find out the best one. So, in 
our proposed algorithm we removed the need to define a threshold value. The algorithm is intelligent and determines 
the threshold automatically.

Comment: Could you please summarize the goal of the article and the algorithm? A title would be nice as well to avoid link rot.

Comment: so where does the term "Pixel with impulse noise" from? It does not exist in the code. Not sure what kind of answer you expect for your question, then

Comment: If X(i,j) ≠ Impulse pixel  here this indicates that!

Comment: Speed of recursive algorithms: Matlab < Python < C .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the paper it seems that the "impulse pixels" are just the noisy pixels, in the case of salt & pepper noise. Furthermore, it also seems that the algorithm provides an "intelligent" mechanism to calculate the denoised value of a noisy pixel if its value is above a threshold (which it calculates adaptively).

So, what about "If X(i,j) ≠ Impulse pixel " ? Well, apparently, the authors assume to know (!) which pixels are noisy (!!), which makes the whole thing rather ridiculous, since this info is almost impossible to know.

I might also add that the rather stunning results presented in the paper are most probably due to this fact.

P.S. Regarding the argument that <"impulse pixels" are all the pixels a which are either equal to 0 or 255>, it is wrong. The set of pixels that have either 0 or 255 intensity value, includes the noisy pixels **as well as** proper pixels that just happen to have such a value. In this case, the algorithm will most probably collapse since it will denoise healthy pixels as well.

Comment: ... I thought about that too, but I did not find any sentence in the article stating that they know which pixels are noisy. Did you find one? Anyway, I think we agree that this is not a good paper...

Comment: @vini, what do you mean? You want a better article to suppress salt and pepper noise?

Comment: @vini, the ones that can get away with it!

Comment: i thought this would be better because it somehow predicts the impulse pixels on its own and that would work wonders but now i am not able to find how it does so

Comment: Well, in the introduction of the paper there is a paragraph stating" ...This is different from grayscale images where salt and pepper noise could be
distinguished as pixels having big difference in the amplitude compared with their neighborhood pixels. A new method was proposed in [8] specifically for binary
images of engineering drawing. Hence, we have incorporated a new method to classify such pixels as 'good but marked noisy' pixels". So maybe [8] has some hints, but again i find the paper rather "staged".

Comment: yes i found that but the paper was presented at Proceedings of the World Congress on Engineering and Computer Science 2011 Vol I
WCECS 2011, October 19-21, 2011, San Francisco, USA which is says so!!  i dun knw what organisation it is

Answer (score 2):

The article you are trying to implement is obviously badly written...
For instance in the algorithm `w` means 2 things: the size of the window, and the number of white pixels!!!

Both the step 1 and 7, are refering to the same loop.

Anyway, to me, **the "impulse pixels" are all the pixels a which are either equal to 0 or 255.**

Basically, they are the pixels which are part of the "salt and pepper" noise.

So basically, you can find them by doing:

```
[impulsepixelsY,impulasPixelX]=find((im==0)|(im==255));
```

Comment: I needed a way of finding these pixels (impulse)